# Using VBA to select, edit and press enter on specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a macro to take variable text to create a formula and the last step is to get the cell to update. For example after the user selects their options the cell will read =A2 & A3 & A4

I don't want it to say that though I need to output so in the workbook I would copy and paste values to another cell then press F2 and enter. How do I do this in VBA?

I've tried Sendkeys F2 and ENTER but it just brings up an "Object Browser" box in VBA and I have no idea why. I just want to click the cell, edit it, and press enter

Comment: The reason that SendKeys is bringing up the Object Browser in *VBE* is that the SendKeys is going to the *VBE* rather than the worksheet............. just make sure the **worksheet is active** and you run the macro from the worksheet rather than the *VBE*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, well that's a weird coincidence.

Comment: @DougGlancy  Not a coincidence at all !!  This topic has been bugging me for a long time !  I immediately new the problem, but not the solution............

Comment: ncastellucci, see this answer to @Gary'sStudent question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38294432/293078